# class not found: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation. DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping

Tags: spring, classnotfound

My dispatcher-servlet file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">




 <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"/>


     <mvc:annotation-driven/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping

" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

after running the application I found the error in server log is

```
class not found: "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation. DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"
```

Someone said me to add appropriate jar files but I already added org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar.

and I added all needed jar.

Comment: You might want to check spring-webmvc jar

There is a starter application at http://tech.lalitbhatt.net/2014/08/spring-hibernate-jquery-tiles-web.html. Check the pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your bean class with-
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping

also remove  `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` from your xml.

You need to do this if you have upgraded from spring 3.1.x to 3.2.x